# Phalcon Security makes page not available

Tags: phalcon

I am using the Security::hash() but whenever the script executes the line, it makes the webpage not available. I remove the line and make it output a string and the script execute it properly. I would like to ask why.

Currently I am working in my local using XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

I further researched about the problem and the $security->hash() crashes and information on this is posted [here](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/2277)